# How to get filename of image used as image fill in table cell?

Tags: keynote, iwork

I'm designing a large photo-based book for a client and he came up with the idea to select the images to include and their sequencing by placing them roughly into a Keynote file. This sounded like a great idea in theory, but it appears that he placed the images as fills inside table cells and now I have no idea how to get their filenames.

The filename is the most important piece of information for me because I have a hard drive filled with 25,000+ images so I can't just search for the right one.

Is there any way to get the filename of an image fill inside a table cell? I know how to do this with a placed image (Image > File Info) but when I click on an image in a table cell all I get is this:

[image: Table cell image]

I really hope I don't have to go back to the client to ask him to do this all over—he's not very tech savvy and he's already put a lot of work into this one file.

I am using Keynote 6.2.2 on OSX 10.9.4.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can find the information you need.

- Save the **Keynote** file.
- Locate the file in **Finder**
- <kbd>⌥</kbd>+Click or Right Click on the file
- In the Dropdown, select **Show Package Contents**
- There you should see a folder **Data** containing all the resources including images used in the file.

**Keynote** files are really packages of files that the application uses to build the presentation.

[image: File structure, Keynote files]

Comment: I had to rename the file from .key and to .zip and then extract it. I didn't have an option in the dropdown to "Show Package Contents"

Answer (score 2):

In the current version of Keynote, you could also click "View > Show Object List" to see the sidebar with full file names of images / videos.

Comment: I was able to drag and drop the file from the sidebar to "Finder"